# MariaDB C api column-wise bind null values

Tags: c++, mariadb

I'm using Mariadb C api. Can I have an example of binding a column data with null values?

I've been following the example:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bulk-insert-column-wise-binding/

The following code is part of what I have:

```
double test_data[1] = {1,NULL,2};
my_bool *isNull = new my_bool[3];
isNull[0] = '0';
isNull[1] = '1';
isNull[2] = '0';

MYSQL_BIND *bind = new MYSQL_BIND;

bind.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE;
bind.buffer = &test_data;
bind.is_null = isNull;

mysql_stmt_attr_set(insertStmt, STMT_ATTR_ARRAY_SIZE,&numRows);
mysql_stmt_bind_param(insertStmt,bind);
mysql_stmt_execute(insertStmt);
```

But it does not bind the NULL value in test_data as null, it returns 0 instead.

This is compiled in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is_null` bind parameter only works if you execute a statement row by row.

When adding batch operations in MariaDB binary protocol, we noticed that several things were missing: e.g. support for default values, ignore value. So instead of adding additional members to the bind structure, we added a union which contains an indicator. Additionally to your data array, you will need also an array of indicators:

```
char indicator[3]= {0, STMT_INDICATOR_NULL, 0};

bind[0].u.indicator= &indicator[0];
```

Beside STMT_INDICATOR_NULL the following indicators are supported:

- STMT_INDICATOR_NTS (zero terminated string, you don't have to provide buffer lengths)
- STMT_INDICATOR_DEFAULT (use columns default value)
- STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE (ignore value for update)
- STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE_ROW (ignore entire row)

You can find some examples of batch execution in [Connector/C unittests](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/3.3/unittest/libmariadb/bulk1.c).

Some comments about your code:

- `test_data[1]` cannot store 3 different values
- bind is a pointer, so you need to assign values with `bind->member` instead of `bind.member`